# How do I find the two newest file in a directory?

Tags: c#

I need to find the two newest files in a directory.

I can find the first using this code:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("f:\\PAB\\bil_prev_ent");
var firstfile = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")
                 orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                 select f).First();
```

I would like to know how I can find the second one file too.

Comment: `.Take(2)` instead of `First()`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry dint see your comment

Comment: @Sajeetharan: it's OK; probably a *materiazation* (say, `.ToArray()`) should be mentioned in the answer ("how I can find the second one file too" - `myfiles[1]`).

Comment: There is a flaw in your code logic. As it will only find the two last files that were created *OR* modified. So it may not be the last two files created, if you take an old file and modifies it, then this will pick it up. What you should be using is `CreationTime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a query and then pick out what you need, for example:

```
var orderedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime);

var newestTwo = orderedFiles.Take(2).ToList();
```

I have used [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574(v=vs.110).aspx) because it doesn't need to load all files into memory.

Comment: This has a flaw. See my comment above

Comment: @Bauss: only OP knows what files he want, if he wants the last two according to `LastWriteTime`(most recently modified files) then he has the right to do. I don't see how this is related to the issue at all.

Comment: This works like a charm, but I use ToArray like suggested

Comment: @Roberto: you're welcome. But you can also use a list if you just want to access file1 and file2, a list-item can be accessed via index too: `var firstFile=list[0];`. The difference between an array and a list is that you can add items later whereas an array has a fixed size.

Comment: I want to reuse this files again. I want to get the number of pages using iTextsharp.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is true, however it could be that OP didn't know about CreationTime. In which case it isn't wrong to point them in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answers. Now how I can have the file full path name?

Comment: The `FileInfo` has a property `FullName`. For example: `string firstFilePath = newestTwo[0].FullName;`

Answer (score 6):

use `Take(n)` instead of `First()`

```
var myfiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")
                 orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                 select f).Take(2);
```

The above will give the files which are modified recently

If you need the files which are created recently, use the **`CreationTime`**

```
var myfiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")
                           orderby f.CreationTime descending
                           select f).Take(2);
```

Comment: This has a flaw. It only finds the two last modified files.

Comment: @Bauss yes modified

Answer (score 0):

The logic I need is the "CreationTime".
Solution number 3 works like a charm but I used ToArray.

So the right code is:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("f:\\PAB\\bil_prev_ent");
var orderedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime);
var newestTwo = orderedFiles.Take(2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2:

now the files are without full path.

How I can have the full path?